# I want to move a item to first index in list. How to simplify code?

Tags: python

This is my code.

```
lst=['0','1','2','3','4']
i = lst.index('2')
lst.pop(i)
tmp=[]
tmp.append('2')
tmp.extend(lst)
lst = tmp
print lst #output:['2','0','1','3','4']
```

Now I want to write pretty code. I think it may be to have room for improvement.So, I hope anyone who can explain and instruct me.Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code

Comment: This doesn't move an item; it creates an entirely new list. If `lst` is the only reference to the list, then it will be fine, but if you have other references, they will still reference the old list.

Comment: Just `lst.insert(0, '2')` right after the `lst.pop(i)` and remove all the `tmp` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted([0,1,2,3,4,5], key=lambda x: x == 2, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative answer you can use slicing :

```
>>> i = lst.index('2')
>>> ['2']+lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]
['2', '0', '1', '3', '4']
```

You can embed it inside a function :

```
>>> def move(elem,l):
...   i = l.index(elem)
...   return [elem]+lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]
... 
>>> move('2',lst)
['2', '0', '1', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Donig it in place (altering the list):

```
lst = lst.pop(lst.index(2)) and (not lst.insert(0, 2)) and lst
```

Creating a new list for the result:

```
[2] + (lst.pop(lst.index(2)) and lst)
```